# MSVC2017 compiler error, Chromium build fails

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, chromium, qtwebengine, visual-c++-2017

So I am on:

- Windows 10
- MS Visual Studio 2017 (2017 build tools)

trying to build:

- `qt5.10.1` with `QtWebEngine`
- using `jom.exe -j4`

and during the `QtWebEngine` build process, this happened:

```
[51/12427] CC obj/third_party/webrtc/common_audio/common_audio_c/sqrt_of_one_minus_x_squared.obj
[52/12427] CC obj/third_party/webrtc/common_audio/common_audio_c/complex_fft.obj
[53/12427] CXX obj/third_party/webrtc/call/call/call.obj
FAILED: obj/third_party/webrtc/call/call/call.obj
ninja -t msvc -e environment.x64 -- "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX64\x64/cl.exe" /nologo /showIncludes  @obj/third_party/webrtc/call/call/call.obj.rsp /c ../../3rdparty/chromium/third_party/webrtc/call/call.cc /Foobj/third_party/webrtc/call/call/call.obj /Fd"obj/third_party/webrtc/call/call_cc.pdb"
C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-5.10.1\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\third_party\webrtc/modules/video_coding/sequence_number_util.h(101): fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
(compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\cxxfe\sl\p1\c\outdname.c', line 5310)
 To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
 Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\xutility(301): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'webrtc::DescendingSeqNumComp<uint16_t,0>' being compiled
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\xutility(301): note: see reference to variable template 'const bool is_empty_v<webrtc::DescendingSeqNumComp<unsigned short,0> >' being compiled
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\xtree(1078): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tree_comp_alloc<_Traits>' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits<uint16_t,webrtc::NackModule::NackInfo,webrtc::DescendingSeqNumComp<uint16_t,0>,std::allocator<std::pair<const uint16_t,webrtc::NackModule::NackInfo>>,false>
        ]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\map(82): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Kty=uint16_t,
            _Ty=webrtc::NackModule::NackInfo,
            _Pr=webrtc::DescendingSeqNumComp<uint16_t,0>,
            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const uint16_t,webrtc::NackModule::NackInfo>>
        ]
C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-5.10.1\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\third_party\webrtc/modules/video_coding/nack_module.h(88): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::map<uint16_t,webrtc::NackModule::NackInfo,webrtc::DescendingSeqNumComp<uint16_t,0>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Kty=uint16_t,
            _Ty=webrtc::NackModule::NackInfo
        ]
[54/12427] CC obj/third_party/webrtc/common_audio/common_audio_c/refl_coef_to_lpc.obj
[55/12427] CC obj/third_party/webrtc/common_audio/common_audio_c/vector_scaling_operations.obj
[56/12427] CC obj/third_party/webrtc/common_audio/common_audio_c/spl_sqrt_floor.obj
[57/12427] CC obj/third_party/webrtc/common_audio/common_audio_c/resample_by_2.obj
[58/12427] CC obj/third_party/webrtc/common_audio/common_audio_c/webrtc_vad.obj
[59/12427] CC obj/third_party/webrtc/common_audio/common_audio_c/spl_init.obj
[60/12427] CXX obj/third_party/webrtc/common_audio/common_audio/sparse_fir_filter.obj
[61/12427] CXX obj/third_party/webrtc/common_audio/common_audio/real_fourier_ooura.obj
[62/12427] CXX obj/third_party/webrtc/common_audio/common_audio_cc/dot_product_with_scale.obj
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
jom: C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-5.10.1\qtwebengine\src\core\Makefile.gn_run.Debug [run_ninja] Error 1
jom: C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-5.10.1\qtwebengine\src\core\Makefile.gn_run [debug-all] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-5.10.1\qtwebengine\src\core\Makefile [sub-gn_run-pro-make_first] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-5.10.1\qtwebengine\src\Makefile [sub-core-make_first] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-5.10.1\qtwebengine\Makefile [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-5.10.1\Makefile [module-qtwebengine-make_first] Error 2

C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-5.10.1>
```

I found this forum with a slightly active/recent question asking about this same issue here:

- [Internal compiler error in outdname.c in VS15.7p3 when building Firefox webrtc code](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/234790/internal-compiler-error-in-outdnamec-in-vs157p3-wh.html)

Is there anything I can do from this point to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrading my version of VS to 2015 allowed me to bypass this compiler error and compile QT successfully.

Comment: I'd report it to MS too. 2017 bugs still have a reasonable chance to be fixed.

Comment: @OfekShilon The link in the OP points to a 'Fixed - Pending Release' thread, where MS was active. However that was fixed around the time I made the post, and I decided to downgrade back then to try and save time. Glad I did as it's still not released!